# $(A\times B)\cup C$ equals?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am preparing for an interview and I am stuck with understanding with this cartesian product. I am able to solve other set theory but not this one. I looked about but couldn't find any help. Please help solve this.

$$(A\times B)\cup C$$

Thanks!

Comment: I do not really know what you would like to solve. All I see is that you start with three sets, $A$, $B$ and $C$. Form this you make the set $A\times B\cup C$. What else do you know about this set? What would you like to know about this set?

Comment: @BabyDragon: What I want to know is that (AuB) u C = A u (B uC), likewise (AXB)UC equals what?

Comment: Am I correct to interpret the question as "is their a law of sets that like the law, $A\cup (B\cup C)=(A\cup B)\cup C$, for the set $A\times B\cup C$.  If this is the case I am not sure that their is a nice answer to this. If the set $C$ is disjoint from $A\times B$ then I can tell you that the size of the set is $|A||B|+|C|$, where the vertical bars denote the size of the set.

Comment: On the other hand if you are interested in the set, $(A\cup B)\times C=(A\times C)\cup (B\times C)$.

Comment: @Ajax3.14 There is no identity for $(A\times B)\cup C$ that is analogous to $(A\cup B)\cup C = A\cup(B\cup C)$.

Comment: @BabyDragon: Yes, you are right, am looking for law of set for (AXB)UC. I too think there isn't one but thought to make sure. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @MJD: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Think this way, $A \times B$ is the set of pairs $(a,b)$ where $a \in A$, $b\in B$. $C$ can be any set whatsoever. By taking the union you are just "adding" elements in $C$ to the bag of pairs $(a,b)$. There need not be any connection between $C$ and $A \times B$. It is like putting apples into a bag filled with oranges.

Answer (score 0):

It is the set of items in AxB or C or both that is x such that x is in AXB or x in C or both.

Comment: What I want to know is that (AuB) u C = A u (BuC), likewise (AXB)UC equals what?